# Why is my ruby code leaking memory?

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks

I'm working on a project where there is this test, and it leaks memory. Can someone please explain to me why? We're suspecting cinch code to be leaky but we're not sure.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'time'
require 'cinch'
require 'cinch/user_list'

CURATORS =   [
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  "one",
  "two",
  "three"
]

bot = Cinch::Bot.new do
  configure do |c|
    c.nick = "Redw0od"
    c.password = "oauth:fgbz5f1qiqvriyp0tz6dqpb3ukverl"
    c.realname = "Redwood"
    c.server = "irc.twitch.tv"
    c.channels = CURATORS.map { |c| '#' + c }
    # c.channels = ["#eulcs2"]

  end

  on :connect do |m, *args|

    m.bot.irc.send("CAP REQ :twitch.tv/commands")
    m.bot.irc.send("CAP REQ :twitch.tv/tags")
    m.bot.irc.send("CAP REQ :twitch.tv/membership")

  end

  on :catchall do |m|
    synchronize(:logmutex) do

    end
  end
end

bot.loggers.level = :error
bot.start
```

Comment: It might not be in this code at all. Maybe it's a dependent library? You'll need to delete bits of code until it goes away, then add those back in until you narrow down the root cause.

Comment: @tadman Or use a profiler.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've found profilers to be unreliable when it comes to tracking down orphaned objects, circular structures the garbage collector doesn't pick up. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @tadman: It depends on the profiler, I guess. The memory profiler in Eclipse is really good, and there are proprietary ones that are even better. The Java space has some of the best "runtime comprehension" tooling in the industry. I don't understand why the Ruby community doesn't make more use of that. The way JRuby is implemented means that Ruby objects are just Java objects, and so, any Java tooling works mostly out-of-the-box.

Comment: There are a couple of blog posts and lightning talks by Charles Nutter, for example, talking specifically about memory profiling.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I've had problems like this and tried to crack it with JRuby but it's often a case of getting way too much data and no clear answers. Depends on the type of leak you're trying to narrow down.

Comment: I guess I'll go with `ruby-prof` to analyze this script?